# Django-channels is not showing Channel layer default (asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer) on server startup

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

For some reason I am unable to connect to my redis server ever through I have daphne, redis, and django-channel. My configurations are below:

```
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
      "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "workscouter.routing.channel_routing",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis-channel-1", 6379), ("redis-channel-2", 6379)],
       },
   },
}
```

Comment: Is your redis running on that port ?

Comment: DId you install `asgi_redis` too? Is there any error message?